# .htaccess and regular expression remove part of the uri

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I would like to redirect path like this

`http://www.example.com/uploads/2017/10/image.ext/version/?id=87988984632`

to

`http://www.example.com/uploads/2017/10/image.ext`

where extension could be whatever image or video extension.
I'm can detect the last part with this `\/version\/(.*)$` but I can't remove from the uri.

---

### Update:

This is my .htaccess and I'm using Wordpress

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule \/version\/(.*)$ 
</IfModule>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: When you enter `http://www.example.com/uploads/2017/10/image.ext` in browser, does it work and show correct image file in browser?

Comment: @anubhava In this case I get 404

Comment: @anubhava sorry I didn't read well your question. If I type `http://www.example.com/uploads/2017/10/image.ext` it works. I see the picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this new redirect before other WP rules:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.+)/version/?$ /$1? [L,NC,NE,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```